# AngularJS Dirty Marker and Blanks

Tags: angularjs

I prepared a JSFiddle to demonstrate a problem we currently have.

An Input Text Field will remember all leading or trailing Blanks but Model will not be updated. So I've no chance to trim those Blanks and update Scopevar by $resource (or by anything else).

Value of Input Field will keep the Blanks until Scopevar is overridden by other Value.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/2rdVv/4/

Can somebody explain this behavior? Bug or Feature?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="element.name" maxlength="100" />
```

```
$scope.loadFirstValue = function() {
    $scope.element = {
        name : 'Superhero'
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you can change this behavior in newer versions.

1. Update angular to 1.1.x or greater
2. Use [ng-trim](https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.1/docs/api/ng.directive:input.text) on your input

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/keL8H/1/

```
<input type="text" ng-model="element.name" maxlength="100" ng-trim="false" />
```

Comment: This fixed the problem, but I still REALLY want to know why the original version behaves the way it does.

Answer (score 0):

Its a normal behavior , that should be exactly like this, its a 2 way data binding .
[read more about it](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding)

[image]